# Java split on - and + basis

Tags: java, split

I have a list of strings

0-30
31-60
61-90
91-120
365+

I want a **regex** which can be put into java split method to get the first no, i.e

0
31
61
91
365

Currently I am  using this logic:

```
        if(str.endsWith("+") ){
            str= str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
        }
        String Num = str.split("-")[0];
```

Is there any better way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String[] splitArray = subjectString.split("[+-]\\d*\\s*");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 String pattern = "[+-]\\d*\\s*";
     String digits = "0-30 31-60 61-90 91-120 365+";


 Pattern splitter = Pattern.compile(pattern);
 String[] result = splitter.split(digits );

 for (String digit: result ) {
     System.out.println("digits = \"" + digit + "\"");
 }
```